# Difference between linkedlist and linkedlist->head

Tags: c

```
==============insert node===============
ListNode *pre, *cur;

    if (ll == NULL || index < 0 || index > ll->size + 1)
        return -1;

    // If empty list or inserting first node, need to update head pointer
    if (ll->head == NULL || index == 0)
    {
        cur = ll->head;
        ll->head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        ll->head->item = value;
        ll->head->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }


    // Find the nodes before and at the target position
    // Create a new node and reconnect the links
    if ((pre = findNode(ll, index - 1)) != NULL)
    {
        cur = pre->next;
        pre->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
        pre->next->item = value;
        pre->next->next = cur;
        ll->size++;
        return 0;
    }

    return -1;
```

Can i ask what is the difference between ll and ll->head? Can i say that ll is the linkedlist as a whole while ll points to the linkedlist head? If so, shouldnt ll->head be empty when ll is empty? why is there a need to check twice?

Comment: [Edit] and show the declaration of `ListNode`and `ll`.

Answer (score 1):

You should share the linked list implementation (struct) of yours. In order to answer we must know what you have implemented.

Assuming you implemented both ll (LinkedList) and Node struct

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
} NODE;

struct linkedlist {
    NODE head;
    NODE tail;

    /* other optional things */
}
```

In this situation `ll` refers to the aggregate data type, which contains pointers to your linkedlist's start and end points, which are head pointer and tail (optional) pointer.

`ll->head` refers to a NODE struct pointer that is building blocks of your linkedlist, which is also the starting point of the linkedlist.